# Do we have Sequence in Sybase

Tags: sequence, sybase

I see tutorial talking about Sequence with syntax and example.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1601/doc/html/saiq-create-sequence-statement.html

But when I try creating sequence in Syabse through Squirrel, I get below error.

```
Error: 'SEQUENCE' is not a recognized CREATE option.

SQLState:  ZZZZZ
ErrorCode: 155
```

Then how do we create auto increment unique identifier in Sybase.

How do we use Identity in Sequence. How come sequence available in one Sybase version and not in another.

I connect to sybase using below dependency.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sybase.jdbcx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  You will need to specify which product you are referring to.  The documentation you linked to is for Sybase IQ, is that what you are using?

Comment: @Michael : I have edited with the jar I am using in application. I use SQuirreL SQL Client to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence as an object does not exist in Sybase ASE (assumption). The equivalent functionality is done using identity columns.

```
create table test_tab (
    test_tab_id     int          identity,
    test_tab_name   varchar(30)  not null )
go

insert into test_tab (test_tab_name) values ('Hello') 
go
insert into test_tab (test_tab_name) values ('World') 
go
select * from test_tab
go
```

Result

> (1 row affected)
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> test_tab_id test_tab_name
>
> ---
>
> ```
>        1 Hello                                                        
>        2 World
> ```
>
> (2 rows affected)

Answer (score 2):

One more point to add on identity is:

Once you truncate the table and insert data the old value of the identity is taken and then incremented.

Example:

```
select * from test_tab
go

2 rows 
1 hello
2 world

Truncate the table test_tab
go


insert into test_tab (test_tab_name) values ('Hai') 
go
insert into test_tab (test_tab_name) values ('done') 
go
select * from test_tab
go
```

You will get as below

```
3 hai
4 done
```

Comment: How do you get the latest identity value ? like we have currval() for sequence in sql.

Answer (score -1):

can we assign the sequence per combination

E.g.
       1 ABC

```
   2 ABC

   3 ABC

   4 ABC

  1  KLO

  2  KLO

  3  KLO
```